# Problem with unit test durning testing HiltViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I try to test function from my viewModel, and all the time I'm getting this error:
"No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation."

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class ActiveWorkoutViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase
    private lateinit var viewModel: ActiveWorkoutViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()

        viewModel = ActiveWorkoutViewModel(appDatabase)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Calculating the distance by gps location points`() {

        val pointsList = mutableListOf(
            "50.830315, 19.202589", "50.836169, 19.203787"
        )

        val result = viewModel.calculateDistance(
            pointsList,
            workoutId = 0
        )

        val expectedValue = 650

        assertEquals(expectedValue, result)

    }
}
```